# How can I debug and find the reason for stuck SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSIS package and it is running for long time. When I checked the All messages from the All Execution report in server, I saw that it is in Execute phase is beginning. Please check the below screenshot.

[image]

Please direct me how to debug this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Warning message is:

> The lookup ... encountered duplicate reference key values when caching reference data. This error occurs in Full Cache mode only. Either remove the duplicate key values, or change the cache mode to PARTIAL or NO_CACHE."

Please verify that you don't have duplicate values on the columns that you've connected your input and the reference table.

If you are connecting `col1` in the lookup table then run a query to check if duplicates exists, example:

```
SELECT col1,Count(*) FROM LookupTable
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

**Similar Issues**

- [Error when Executing LOOKUP is SSIS](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic379108-148-1.aspx)
- [Lookup Transformation raises warning of duplicate key values...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce1ac9b7-639a-45e1-a447-fedaf833e93d/lookup-transformation-raises-warning-of-duplicate-key-values?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [SQL Server Integration Services – Error – “Warning: The Lookup transformation encountered duplicate reference key values when caching reference data"](https://learningintheopen.org/2016/10/29/sql-server-integration-services-warning-the-lookup-transformation-encountered-duplicate-reference-key-values-when-caching-reference-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the duplicates on the Lookup Key (not on its individual column members). The following query may be used to identify de duplicate records an to identify the perfect Lookup Key:

```
select row_number() over(partition by /*LookUp Key*/ [Column1], [Column2], ..., [ColumnN]
                     order by /*LookUp Key*/ [Column1], [Column2], ..., [ColumnN]
                     ) row_
    ,*
from [Database].schema.[Reference Table]
--where 1=1
```

When the "row_" column is greater than 1, it means your Lookup Key references duplicate records. In order to solve this, you may try another Look Up Key for the reference data or you may get unique Reference Data records using the following code in the SSIS Look Up Task for the Lookup Key above:

```
--Reference data without Lookup key duplicates
with reference_data as (
select   [Column1]
        ,[Column2]
        ,...
        ,[ColumnN]

        ,row_number() over(partition by /*LookUp Key*/partition by /*LookUp Key*/ [Column1], [Column2], ..., [ColumnN]
                     order by [Reference Data Unique Key] desc
                     ) row_
from [Database].schema.[Reference Table]
)
select [Column1]
    ,[Column2]
    ,...
    ,[ColumnX]
from reference_data
where row_ = 1
```

In general, the **LookUp Key (not the columns that make it up) must be unique** for this error not being prompted.